# Python: Unable to search by attrs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to access a table in a huge html file. The table is referred in the table of content. So, I wrote code to get the href. Then I used the href value to locate the table. It works sometimes. Otherwise, it returns none. Here is the html exerpts:
Table of content:

```
<a href="#h54"><font size="2">Summary Compensation Table</font></a>
```

Table location is below this tag:

```
<a name="h54"></a>
```

Here is my code:

```
    def your_filter(tag, value):
        return any(tag[key] == value for key in tag.attrs.keys())

    all_linked = soup.find_all("a", text=re.compile(r'summary compensation', re.IGNORECASE), href=True)
    if len(all_linked)>0:
        table_link = all_linked[0]['href']
        tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: your_filter(tag, table_link[1:]))
        goto_table = soup.find(tags[0].name, tags[0].attrs)
```

Here tags return none.

Comment: Are there urls to go with this we can test with? I get `tags` as `[<a name="h54"></a>]` if I run your code as I think you are trying to run it.

Comment: Here is the url: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/72741/000104746918002070/a2234804zdef14a.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM is quite "flat" and you are finding a nested element when you actually need to be higher up the DOM, at the level of one of the parent divs, and then looking for a sibling `div` that has your target table. One way might be as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pandas import read_html as rh

r = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/72741/000104746918002070/a2234804zdef14a.htm', headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
df = rh(str(soup.select_one('div:has(b:-soup-contains("SUMMARY COMPENSATION TABLE")) ~ div div > table')))[0]
df.dropna(how='all', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.columns = df.iloc[1, :]
df = df.iloc[3:, :]
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)
df
```

Comment: Got your point. But this code did not work. I resolved it with this:                                        
                       for i in soup.find_all("font"):
                            if i.text.strip().lower() == 'summary compensation table':
                                goto_table=i

Comment: I tested the code and it works just fine. What was the error in your case?

Comment: The error msg is : "NotImplementedError: ':-soup-contains' pseudo-class is not implemented at this time"

Comment: Use :contains instead for older soupsieve versions or upgrade your bs4

Comment: `df = rh(str(soup.select_one('div:has(b:contains("SUMMARY COMPENSATION TABLE")) ~ div div > table')))[0]`